# How create WMS layer in GeoServer by REST API?

Tags: postgresql, rest, geoserver

In `PostgreSQL` I have a scheme called `geo`. Inside that scheme, I have a table with a column which has a `geometry` data type.

I am new in `GeoServer` and want to know how to create `WMS` layer by `REST API` with data of that remote PostgreSQL database? According to the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/latest/en/api/1.0.0/layers.yaml) I need to create workspace and datastore first, right? I'm a little confused. What sequence of actions should be? I will be grateful for any example!

Result of curl request:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REST API works in exactly the same manner as the GUI, so the process is that you can optionally create a new **workspace** or use an existing one, you then create a **store** inside a **workspace** and then create **layer**s from the store. Any layer will automatically become available as a WMS layer.

1. [Create a new PostGIS store](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/stores.html#adding-a-postgis-database-store), generate a file with the connection details:

```
      <dataStore>
        <name>nyc</name>
        <connectionParameters>
          <host>localhost</host>
          <port>5432</port>
          <database>nyc</database>
          <user>bob</user>
          <passwd>postgres</passwd>
          <dbtype>postgis</dbtype>
        </connectionParameters>
      </dataStore>
```

and POST it to the REST endpoint

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -T <file.xml> -H "Content-type: text/xml"
    http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/<WORKSPACENAME>/datastores
```

2. Then [publish the table as a layer](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/stores.html#publishing-a-table-from-an-existing-postgis-store)

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<featureType><name>buildings</name></featureType>" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/acme/datastores/nyc/featuretypes
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have already created a workspace and a datastore. 
When you make POST request to the geoserver to create the layer you just set auth parameters. Is it necessary to send meta parameters to geoserver? For example `srs`, `crs` e.t.c.? I am little bit confused about it?

Comment: there is no need, a postgis based layer works those out for itself

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As I said before I already created `workspace` (georeports) and `datastore` (subscribers). I tried to test your second curl. Unfortunately, it raises an error. Server returns `400 Bad Request` and return such message: `Trying to create new feature type inside the store, but no attributes were specified`.  It seems like I miss some attributes. Do you have any ideas? Also, can you check my POST again, please? I add pictures with information.

Comment: As I understand `buildings` which you set in `<featureType><name>buildings</name></featureType>` is a name of the table in the PostgreSQL database, right?! I changed the name. In my case it calls `layers`. In that case curl request return `500Internal Server Error` with such message: `Resource named 'layers' already exists in store: 'subscribers'`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Also I notice that in GUI when I tried to create the layer it ask to set attributes like `srs`, `nativeBoundingBox` and `latLonBoundingBox`.

Comment: My next `GET` request `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers` return list of all layers. I found my layer on that list. Then I deleted my layer with `DELETE` request. After that, I checked the list of layers again. My layer disappeared from the list. After that I make curl request again but it raise the same error as in the last comment: `Resource named 'layers' already exists in store: 'subscribers'`. It`s so strange.

Comment: Well, finally I [found](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168165/geoserver-rest-api-delete-layer) that I need to make 2 `DELETE` requests, if I want to delete the layer correctly. After that I can make your second curl without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

***optional.
Publishing a table from an existing PostGIS store.
on php curl.***

```
function curl_post($url,$params) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"user:password");//--> on geoserver.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Receive server response ...


$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
return $response;
}

 //- table_name      : xxx 
 //- work_space_name : your_workspace 
 //- store_name    : dbtest


$layer_name = "xxx";

$params ="
    <featureType>
      <name>".$layer_name."</name>
      
      <nativeName>".$layer_name."</nativeName>
      
      <title>".$layer_name."</title>
      
      <keywords>
        <string>".$layer_name."</string>
        <string>features</string>
      </keywords>
      
      <srs>EPSG:3857</srs>
      
      <nativeBoundingBox>
        <minx>1.0836244E7</minx>
        <maxx>1.1759454E7</maxx>
        <miny>625842.375</miny>
        <maxy>2328151.75</maxy>
      </nativeBoundingBox>
      
      <latLonBoundingBox>
        <minx>97.34363607648459</minx>
        <maxx>105.63697261100442</maxx>
        <miny>5.613037739416236</miny>
        <maxy>20.464604971116074</maxy>
        
      </latLonBoundingBox>
      
      <projectionPolicy>FORCE_DECLARED</projectionPolicy>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <metadata>
        <entry key=\"cachingEnabled\">false</entry>
      </metadata>
      <maxFeatures>0</maxFeatures>
      <numDecimals>0</numDecimals>
    </featureType>
";

$str_url = "http://xxx.co.uk/geoserver/rest/workspaces/**your_workspace**/datastores/**your_data_store**/featuretypes";

$rs = curl_post($str_url, $params);
```